# Jenkins hit REST endpoint

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way I can have a post build event that will hit a specified REST endpoint with the URL of the artefact that was uploaded to nexus as part of the deploy? (Or at least access to the pom parameters so I can build the url)

I've already had a look at this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin but it doesn't look like what I am after.

Comment: Whats wrong with HTTP Request Plugin?

Comment: @Slav - simple doesn't work. I've decided to use a powershell script instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a Powershell script to make a HTTP request with some parameters.